# ArrayList with arrays in it. How to get them out. code is posted

Tags: java, arraylist

Little problem.. i want to add some arrays to my arraylist and later get acces to print them out.
Her is my code..

```
 import java.util.*;
 class List
{
 private ArrayList<int[]> X;
 private int[] list;

public X()
{
    X = new ArrayList<int[]>();
}

public void addList(int[] list)
{
     this.X.add(list);
}

public void showList(int listNumber)
{
    System.out.println(X.get(listNumber));
}
```

Problem is im not getting my list out, but the int code something ... dunno what it really is..

Comment: naming your class `List`, while importing `java.util.*` [which also contains the interface `List`] is a bad practice. In addition, you also refer to your arrays as a list.... In my opinion there are way too many things names 'list', you should rethink how you name your classes/variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because arrays `toString()` which is called here prints out array reference, not it's contents.

Use instead custom output:

```
    for (int i : X.get(listNumber))
        System.out.print(i + " ");
```

Or, as AlexR proposed, better use provided JDK method `Arrays.toString()`;

By the way, you don't need to prefix `this.` everywhere in your class' code.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in line `System.out.println(X.get(listNumber));`. Every java object has method `toString()`. Arrays also have such method but its implementation shows the array reference. To print the array content either iterate over it and print element-by-element or use utility like `Arrays.toString()`:

`System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(X.get(listNumber)));`

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over all integer arrays in X and in each item (array) print it elements.
This function will do the job for you.

```
public void printAll(){
for(int [] item:X){
 for(int num :item){
  System.out.print(num);
  }
   System.out.println();
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Arrays class from `java.util.Arrays`:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(X.get(listNumber)));
```

Just printing out an array prints out its memory location, so to get the actual values, you have to get each element individually, which is what `Arrays.toString()` does for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the array. If you want to display the results of the array you need to do loop through each value in `X.get(listNumber)` and display the results of the loop.